# Kosher alternative for blood sausage

Tags: substitutions, kosher

The title explains it all, is there a kosher substitute for blood sausage?*

---

Blood sausage is not kosher due to the inclusion of blood, the consumption of which is forbidden by Jewish law.

Comment: What are you doing that needs blood sausage? If we know how you want to use it, we are likely more able to recommend an alternative.

Comment: @Catija, I'm actually just curious, as I have absolutely no reference point, which makes assessing recipes which would otherwise require it difficult at best.

Comment: In Scotland the vegetarian alternative to black pudding would be white pudding which is oatmeal, onions, spices and beef suet.  One would have to be careful to ensure it was the traditional beef suet one rather than some cheaper version with pork fat.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you consider some kosher sausage to be a sausage, and therefore a substitute for a non-kosher sausage.

No, if you want a sausage which is "like" blood sausage. It's pretty much like itself, and not much else, other than "it's a sausage", in which case, see above.